# Ruby on Rails - find Next and previous date based on param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have added `activity_logs` to my application and I show `@activities` based on giving `param_date` to url.

*My link/path looks like:*

`http://localhost:3000/users/activity_logs?param_date=2016-09-12`.

I do much like to add **Next day** & **Previous day** on same page. How can I find the **Next day** & **Previous day** based on the date I have on `param_date`.

Ex: `= link_to 'Next day', activity_logs_path(param_date: date)`

So basically if `param_date` is **2016-09-30**, Next Day would be: **2016-10-01** and Prev day: **2016-09-29**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
prev_data = (Date.parse(params[:param_date]) -1).strftime('%F')
next_data = (Date.parse(params[:param_date]) +1).strftime('%F')
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby's `Date` class has a [`next_day`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-next_day) and a [`prev_day`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-prev_day) method:

Parse the date from the `params` in your controller

```
@date = Date.parse(params[:param_date])
```

and then generate the links in your views like this

```
link_to('Next day',     activity_logs_path(param_date: @date.next_day))

link_to('Previous day', activity_logs_path(param_date: @date.prev_day))
```